# Delete method not working properly, can't see why? Python, tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

When this function runs the first time, the return value is correct, but the 2nd time it runs the new value is appended to the previous value. the t1.delete(0,END) is supposed to delete the old value before the new one is generated but I can't see why it's not.

```
def calculate_area():
    CA=float(e1_value.get())*float(e2_value.get())
    t1.delete(0,END)#Why doesn't this delete previous return value?
    t1.insert(END,CA)
```

Answer (score 1):

it would be better if you include the whole code. i don't see any reason
not to delete the previous value of t1 entry.